# ldap_add(): Add: Referral on adding new user

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to add active directory new user, using web app written in *`PHP`* and *`XAMPP`* as a server, and the *`XAMPP`* its self is self hosted on `windows server 2016`

I can get the list of the active directory user on my screen, but the problem occurs when i try to add new user to the active directory, it returns to asking me to input some `referral`, and i don't know what referral is..

Comment: Could you provide a [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the fully qualified DN (you can change the company-specific information in the dc= components)

Answer (score 0):

A referral is result code saying that the request you sent cannot be processed by the server, but can be if you redirect the connection and request to the `referral` URL.
Some LDAP client libraries have options to follow referrals automatically.